# XML Serialize, ошибка "недоступен в силу его уровня защиты". C#

Tags: c#, list, serialize

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Users> lol = new List<Users>();
        lol.Add(new Users("maks", "kovtun", 234234, "учасник"));
        lol.Add(new Users("Jeka", "SKRT", 32552, "активований"));
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Users>));//тут ОШИБКА

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, lol);
        }
    }


    [Serializable]

    public class Users
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public int ID;
        public string Status;
        public Users() { }
        public Users(string fName, string lName, int id, string status)
        {
            this.FirstName = fName;
            this.LastName = lName;
            this.ID = id;
            this.Status = status;
        }
```

Что я не так зделал ? Ошибка - "недоступен в силу его уровня защиты. Возможна обработка только общих типов".

Comment: Данный код должен работать без ошибок. Приведённая ошибка возникнет, если у класса `Users` убрать модификатор `public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у Вас:

`class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)`

то либо:
1. объявите `public class Program`
или 
2. Вынесите декларацию класса `Users` из класса `Program`

Comment: Телепатия высшего уровня :)

Comment: Да, действительно: наверняка `Users` вложен в `Program`. Я о таком не подумал.

Comment: @Leonid а как удалить определенного юзера?

Comment: @Eugene ну Вы же определили List<Users> lol = new List<Users>(); Вот и удаляйте. Напр. lol.Remove(lol[1]); в т.ч и выбрав удаляемый элемент с помощью LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Если класс создается с модификатором internal, Замените модификатор на public.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).